# x86 Emulator for Linux with detailed debugging

Tags: linux, c, assembly, emulators

I am looking for a x86 emulator so that I can run my Linux kernel inside it. I am specifically looking for an emulator that shows all the function calls in C/Assembly level from bootloader, all the way to kernel loading. Moreover, it should be capable of showing the RAM memory layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of kernel debugging solutions available; here are a couple I've used:

- [bochs](http://bochs.sourceforge.net/), a full-system emulator, has a nice [built-in debugger](http://bochs.sourceforge.net/doc/docbook/user/internal-debugger.html) (with an optional GUI), as well as support for [remote debugging using `gdb`](http://bochs.sourceforge.net/doc/docbook/user/debugging-with-gdb.html);
- [QEMU](http://wiki.qemu.org/Main_Page), another full-system emulator (which also supports CPU-only, per-process emulation) also supports [remote debugging using `gdb`](http://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/Debugging).

Both of these can freeze the CPU at startup of the emulated system, which allows the bootstrap to be debugged. When used as targets for `gdb`, they also support attaching source code so you can follow C code (or theoretically anything `gdb` supports).